# Rattling noise while accelerating in 2011 FORD FUSION AWD 3.0L

Tags: ford, noise, drivetrain, fusion

My 2011 awd  fusion is make a rattling noise at the front drivers side of the car. The noise is only present while accelerating. There is no noise when the car is rolling without acceleration at constant speed , whether it be in neutral or in gear. There is also no noise when revving the engine in neutral . My current guesses are a wheel bearing, CV axle, the front AWD transfer case,  something in the transmission, or the timing chain. I had the AWD set up on the car but recently pulled the driveshaft off after something seized up and I had to drive the last few blocks to the house in reverse. 2011 SEL 3.0L v6 awd . What might it be ?

Comment: I am quite certain the noise is coming from the damaged transfer case. I believe the transfer case failed causing the seizing sensation

Answer (score 1):

If that problem occurs when the car is in neutral and nothing engaged, check for any lose bolts or brackets this can make a lot of noise under load.